# Mongoose like SQL Distinct with latest date

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I try to find all data in my collection with mongoose but I have some problems to understand.
Now I use

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const CaseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    szenario: {
        type: String,
        default: 'deprecated'
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        default: 'test'
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

const Case = mongoose.model('tests', CaseSchema);

module.exports = Case;
```

May idea of the call is:

```
Case.find().distinct(name).exec();
```

But how I can select it distinct for the newest date with mongoose?

Comment: What do you mean by "latest date"? If you have `{name:"foo", date:yesterday}` and `{name:"foo", date:today}`, what distinct do you want? Distinct of name ("foo") or ...?

Comment: Sorry for this confusion, with latest date I was talking about "today" in your question.

Comment: Does it resolves your question: `Case.find({date:{$gte:new Date('2020-02-23')}}).distinct(name).exec();`?

Comment: Hmm, maybe I have misunderstood your comment. The date is something I do not know, some of the entries are not current date. Like 100 different cases each with 20 different dates. I want to have finally just the case with the newest date -> newest = most current date. So first filter is name (distinct) and seconds filter is date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get distinct name with lastest date, you need perform MongoDB aggregation with [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) operator:

```
Case.aggregate([
  {
    $sort: {
      name: 1,
      date: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$name",
      data: {
        $last: {
          date: "$date",
          _id: "$_id"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: "$data._id",
      date: "$data.date",
      name: "$_id"
    }
  }
]).exec((err, cases) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(cases);
});
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Xl6g1ueso8f)

Comment: Many thanks. I can confirm that this work, but I get lost into the issue that I will not get the _id of the referenced cases. The list is perfect but how to process later wit the elements out of this list? For this I need the unique _id of the cases. How to get this in console.log?

Comment: @ingo check again please

Comment: Wow, yes now I understand. Sometimes some lines explain it better than thousand words. Many thanks.